# How to match and replace text with integer and change text but not the integer?

Tags: regex, android-studio

I want to match `lastBid = \d` where `\d` is integer and add next line below `lastBid = \d` with `randomText` but not change the integer

For example:

`lastBid = 3` to

```
lastBid = 3
randomText
```

How can I do it? If I can't maybe there is other way to do it (not in Android Studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parens `()` for grouping. I think referencing a group in android studio would be `$n` where `n` is the captured group number.

So try find: `(lastBid = \d)` replace with: `$1\nrandomtext`

Comment: see also "backreference."

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm now reading [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern?authuser=1) documentation about backreferences but for me it's still hard to understand what is `\k` and how did you understand that n is captured group number. Now I want to try to the group but I don't know how. I'm trying something like `(k\<groupName>lastBid = \d+)` replacing with `$groupName\nrandomtext ` or creating 2 groups by `(lastBid = \d+)|(lastBid = \d)` and replacing by `$1\nrandomtext|$2\nrandomtexts` do you know any good source to better understand these things?

Comment: REGEX is very difficult and I usually resort to trial and error to be frank. The problem with regular expressions is that each tool often has it's own "flavor." I use it mostly in Notepad++ where groups are referenced using \1\2\3 instead of $1$2$3, but I knew enough to look at grouping references in replace in the androi studio docs before I answered. For real help with regex, try the stackoverflow stack

Comment: But you will find lots of resources if you look for "regex" or "regular expressions". 1 random link: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html